# How to Create Associative array in JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var stds = [];
<?php
  foreach ($this->students as $key => $value){
?>
    var smval = "<?php echo $value?>";
    stds.push( smval );
<?php
}
?>
alert("stds"+stds);
```

alert("stds"+stds);//print abc,bcd,efg so on...

The above code works fine for pushing Student Names. 
Now I want to  push student CODES also which is there in value $key.
How can i create an associative array to do that

Comment: This seems to be *badly* vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest and safest way to do this is to convert the PHP object into a JavaScript object literal with [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var students = <?= json_encode($this->students) ?>;

// sample usage
alert (students["Tony"]);   // Tony's student code
alert (students["Geezer"]); // Geezer's student code
alert (students["Vinnie"]); // etc.
```

Comment: Two bad things about this example: you don't need to put quotes around what json_encode returns (or call jQuery.parseJSON) and you don't need to escape quotes, json_encode always returns something that is valid JavaScript, therefore you can just use `var students = <?= json_encode($this->students) ?>;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var stds = [];
<?php
  foreach ($this->students as $key => $value){
?>
    stds.push( { 'name': '<?php echo $value; ?>', 'code': '<?php echo $key; ?>' } );
<?php
  }
?>
alert("stds"+stds);
```

To be precise: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript. You can either use the code above, which gives you an array of objects containing your data or the code below, which gives you an object similar to the one you have in PHP.

```
var stds = {};
<?php
  foreach ($this->students as $key => $value){
?>
    stds[ '<?php echo $key; ?>' ] = '<?php echo $value; ?>';
<?php
  }
?>
alert("stds"+stds);
```

Comment: when i try to print the stds in the alert .It is printing object , object

Comment: it is an array of objects in the first code example. you would access each entry by `stds[0].name`, for example.

Comment: Incorrect.  `{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}` is an associative array (ie, a hash).

Comment: that would be an object. it does _not_ have any of the array prototype's functions and properties like `length` or `map`.

Comment: Google "JavaScript associative array".  Plenty of information on this out there.  You're confusing the array datatype with general objects.  All objects in JavaScript are also associative arrays.  Even functions.

Comment: I like to refer more to the EcmaScript Spec [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.4) and [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5) then to blogs. But you may stick to your notation, if you wish to.

Comment: An array in JS is a special type of object with some (predefined) functions attached to it.

Comment: I'm sorry to be pedantic, but arrays are always objects.  Objects are not always arrays.  You're requirement that a data structure to be called an "associative array" must have the methods of the Array type is not correct.  The spec you are linking to agrees.

Comment: Spec: "Object Literal: ...It is a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values, enclosed in curly braces."  In other words, an associative array (aka, a Map.  aka, a Dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

```
var stds = <?php echo json_encode( $this->students); ?>;
```

Not sure what keys are in your array

```
alert( stds[0][ key1 ] +'   ' + stds[0][ key2 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do more of a

```
stds[<?php echo $key?>] = '<?php echo $value; ?>';
```

or you can try doing it within an object demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u3Muk/

Comment: Don't do this, you need to escape quotes and newlines in your strings. Just call `json_encode` to do the heavy lifting for you. Converting PHP arrays and values to JS is simpler than most think.